How to get the name of the file which spark generates?
We are writing data frame to a directory like below in pySpark code.
Its writing with file name as "part-****", is there anyway to get the name of the file in code after its written?
In our case there are other diff jobs will be writing file to same target directory so want to know which specific file is generated by this job code.
df.write \
                        .format(file_type) \
                        .option(strings.str_header_lc, header) \
                        .option(strings.str_delimiter_lc, delimiter) \
                        .mode(mode) \
                        .save(path)

Thanks,
Mahendra

What data format are you using for the output? if you are using delta format, it will store the file names under transaction_logs, you should be able to find the details there.
